# inner automorphism induces identity map on group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

I'm taking a course in group cohomology,  and the professor taught the functorial property of the construction of cohomology.  he mentioned that an inner automorphism induces exactly the identity map over cohomology groups; he then said we can easily use this fact to obtain similar facts for cohomology of profinite groups (discrete modules).

I guess this is a trivial fact but I'm a beginner and have no idea with this.  can anyone tell me is this a theorem?  or as an exercise can anyone give me some hint?  thanks!

Comment: This only makes sense for group cohomology with constant coefficients. Then one way to prove this is to use the topological interpretation of cohomology and the fact that inner automorphisms of $G$ are induced  by self-maps $K(G,1)\to K(G,1)$ homotopic to the identity map.

Comment: what does (constant coefficient) mean?  and could you please give a reference for this fact?  sorry I'm a total beginner

Comment: It also makes sense for a non-constant module, but then if the inner automorphism is conjugation by $g$, you also need to consider the map $a\mapsto ga$ on the $G$-module to induce a map in cohomology.

Comment: Cohomology with constant coefficients mean $H^*(G, R)$, where $R$ is a trivial $ZG$-module. Do you know that $H^*(G,R)\cong H^*(K(G,1), R)$? It is in Brown's book, for instance.

Comment: thanks,  I will read related chapters on Brown's famous text before asking further details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are studying group cohomology from the point of view of topology, you are probably used to writing $H^n(G,A)$ where $A$ has a trivial $G$-action (often even $A=\mathbb{Z}$). If you are studying it from an arithmetical point of view (say in the context of class field theory) then usually $A$ will be a non-constant $G$-module. The first setting is of course a special case of the second one, so I will assume that you are using non-trivial modules, and you can adapt the statements for the simpler case.

To induce a map $H^n(G,A)\to H^n(H,B)$, you need a group morphism $\varphi: H\to G$ and a group morphism $f:A\to B$ which are compatible, meaning that $f(\varphi(h)a) = hf(a)$. If $G=H$ and $A=B$, then for any $g\in G$ you get an automorphism $\psi_{g,A}^n: H^n(G,A)\to H^n(G,A)$ by taking $\varphi:G\to G$ to be conjugation by $g$, and $f:A\to A$ is given by $a\mapsto ga$. Of course if $A$ is a constant module then $f$ is just the identity.

Note that this is functorial in the sense that if $A\to B$ is any $G$-morphism, you get a commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^n(G,A) @>{\psi_{g,A}^n}>> H^n(G,A)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
H^n(G,B) @>{\psi_{g,B}^n}>> H^n(G,B).
\end{CD}$$

Now to prove that $\psi_{g,A}^n$ is trivial for all $A$, $g$ and $n$, one possible way is to proceed by induction on $n$. It is of course essentially trivial for $n=0$ (I leave you to check that). Now you can always embed $A$ into some module $I$ such that $H^r(G,I)=0$ for all $r>0$ (for instance an injective module). The short exact sequence
$$0\to A\to I\to B\to 0$$
of $G$-modules (where $B=I/A$) gives the commutative diagram with exact lines:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> H^n(G,B) @>>> H^{n+1}(G,A) @>>> 0\\
@VVV @V{\psi_{g,B}^n}VV @V{\psi_{g,A}^{n+1}}VV @VVV\\
0 @>>> H^n(G,B) @>>> H^{n+1}(G,A) @>>> 0.
\end{CD}$$

Now by induction $\psi_{g,B}^n$ is the identity, and the middle horizontal morphisms, which are the same on both rows, are isomorphisms by exactness, so $\psi_{g,A}^{n+1}$ has to be the identity.

Note that for $n=0$ here this does not exactly work since you only get the zero on the right, but actually surjectivity of the maps $H^n(G,B)\to H^{n+1}(G,A)$ is enough to make the proof work.

Comment: omg,  thank u so much give me some time to read and understand it